# Consider $\dot x$ =$\cos(x+t)$ ,find maximum,minimum and inflection points.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ok this is what I came up with:

First I change $\dot x$ =$\cos(x+t)$ with the change of variables $u=x+t$ then $\dot u=\dot x+1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\dot u=cos(u)+1$, then I solve by separation by parts which I can do if $u\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Then $\frac{\dot u}{\cos(u) +1}=1 \Rightarrow \int\frac{\dot u}{\cos(u) +1}dt=t+C_1 \Rightarrow \tan(\frac{u}{2})+C_2 =t+C_1 \Rightarrow \tan(\frac{u}{2})=t+C_3$ where $C_3=C_1-C_2$

But then $u=2\arctan(t+C_3)$, by undoing the change of variables $u=x+t \Rightarrow x=2\arctan(t+C_3)-t$

Am I right to say x doesnt have a maximum and minima since if $T$ is large enough then $x\approx-(t+\pi)$ as that function diverges in the future and the past? What happened to the restriction of u shouldn't it have given me some bound on x?

Then for the inflection points i'm supposed to derivate twice that function or is there a more qualitative way of calculating them?

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear. Are you looking for the maximum, minimum, and inflection points of the function $x(t)$?

Comment: @Trevor Kafka I think the problem asks for the Maximum, Minimum and inflection points of the solutions of the differential equation. As an update I see that $x(t)=$

Comment: @Trevor Kafka I follow here the thing I wanted to update since is not letting me edit.


As an update I see that $x(t)=-t$ is a solution but that means $0$ is a common point between the general solution I gave and this one, so that means $\dot  x=cos(x+t)$ doesn't satisfy Picard but that is absurd since $f(x,t)=cos(x+t)$ is diferentiable, so that means I'm super confused.

Comment: UPDATE: I just realized I did a mistake $x(t)=-t$ is not a solution obviously.